# Finding the number of white balls in a box given the probability of selection

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

Assume there are two boxes: box A contains $x$ white balls and $y$ black balls, box B contains exactly 6 white balls and 3 black balls. We randomly choose either box A or box B, then randomly sample a ball from the chosen box. The ball turns out to be black. We then perform a second sample of one ball: if we do this with replacement, then the probability of the second ball also being black is $\frac{13}{30}$ and if we perform sampling without replacement the probability is $\frac{17}{50}$. The task is to find $x$ 
My idea is to compute 2 probabilities:
$$P(\text{a black ball is drawn}|\text{prior to that a black ball was drawn with replacement})$$
$$P(\text{a black ball is drawn}|\text{prior to that a black ball was drawn without replacement})$$
Let me show the reasoning for the second one and then the other will be analogous: 
$$P(\text{a black ball is drawn}|\text{prior to that a black ball was drawn without replacement})=\frac{P(\text{a black ball is drawn and prior to that a black ball was drawn without replacement})}{P(\text{a black ball was drawn})}$$
$$P(\text{a black ball was drawn})=P(\text{a black ball was drawn from the first box})+P(\text{a black ball was drawn from the second box})=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{y}{x+y}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{9}={\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\frac{y}{x+y}+\frac{1}{3}\right)}$$
By the same logic
$$P(\text{a black ball is drawn and prior to that a black ball was drawn without replacement})={\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\frac{y(y-1)}{(x+y)(x+y-1)}+\frac{1}{12}\right)}$$
So, the probability is
$$\frac{\frac{y(y-1)}{(x+y)(x+y-1)}+\frac{1}{12}}{\frac{y}{x+y}+\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{17}{50}$$
Doing the same for the probability with replacement we get
$$\frac{\frac{y^2}{(x+y)^2}+\frac{1}{9}}{\frac{y}{x+y}+\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{13}{30}$$
I graphed this system of equations for $x>0$ and $y>0$ and obtained the only solution of $x=y=3$. However, I am not sure that this is the correct approach as I was not able to analytically solve the system. Is my reasoning here correct and if it is, is there a faster way of arriving at this answer?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but the problem seems wrong. If I do the same sample with replacement, both the results should yield the same probability. By "the second ball **also** being black" I presume it is P(first black $\cap$ second black) which necessarily must be a square fraction, but  13/30 is not !

Comment: @trueblueanil I got that $$p\left(\text{Box}-A\right) = \frac{\frac{y}{x+y}}{\frac{y}{x+y} + \frac{2}{3}} = \frac{3y}{4y+x}$$ and $$p\left(\text{Box}-B\right) = \frac{x + y}{4y+x}.$$  Then, I verified that $(x,y) = (3,3) \implies $ $$\left[p\left(\text{Box}-A\right) \times \frac{y}{x+y}\right] + \left[p\left(\text{Box}-B\right) \times \frac{1}{3}\right] = \frac{13}{30}$$ and $$\left[p\left(\text{Box}-A\right) \times \frac{y-1}{x+y-1}\right] + \left[p\left(\text{Box}-B\right) \times \frac{1}{4}\right] = \frac{17}{50}.$$

Comment: To the OP: The Math is very ugly.  Although I didn't scrutinize your work line by line, it seemed like you knew what you were doing.  For what it's worth $\color{red}{\text{Verification}}$ is much cleaner/easier than $\color{red}{\text{Derivation}}$.  I looked at this problem for 30 minutes, and I (also) do not see any elegant derivation of $(x,y) = (3,3).$

Comment: @trueblueanil Typo in my first comment to you.  Denominator for computation of $p\left(\text{Box}-A\right)$ should be $$\frac{y}{x+y} + \frac{\color{red}{1}}{3}.$$